Set all diagonal block matrix be zero matrix in Python
bnds = [(0, 0) if i == j else (0, None) for _ in range(2) for i in range(d) for j in range(d)]

The above code is for a size of dxd matrix. The above code is to force all the diagonal entries of matrix be zero. For all other entries, we just set it to be any number of (0, None), which I believe it is any non-negative number.
Now I need to modify the above code. The original matrix is dxd. Now I have a Kd x Kd matirx, where each d has KxK block matrix. For this large Kd x Kd matrix, I need all diagonal KxK block matrix to be zero matrix.
For example, say d=20 and K=5. Then the matrix of first 5 rows and first 5columns should be zero matrix. The matrix of [6:10, 6:10] should also be zero matrix, etc...
In R, I know the index are
index0 = ((j - 1) * K + 1) : (j * K)
index1 = ((l - 1) * K + 1) : (l * K)

But in Python, the starting and end index are different. I am not sure whether my attempt is correct. My current attempt is:
bnds = []
for i in range(1, K*d+1):
    for j in range(1, K*d+1):
        block_row = (i - 1) // K
        block_col = (j - 1) // K
        row_start = block_row * K + 1
        row_end = row_start + K
        col_start = block_col * K + 1
        col_end = col_start + K
        if block_row == block_col:
            bnds.append((0, 0)) 
        else:
            bnds.append((0, None))

I am a novice in Python. Please comment my above code. Thank you.

why using for i in range(1, K*d+1) to then use i-1? Just use  for i in range(K*d).

You are not using the starts and ends so they can't be wrong...

Pick a (reasonably small) K and d. What do you expect to get for those values? What do you get when you run your code?

@Julien In Python, for num in range(5):
print(num) It returns 0,1,2,3,4. It doesn 't include 5

So? range(1,5+1) is 1,2,3,4,5, and after you subtract 1 from each element it's back to 0,1,2,3,4...

@Julien I see. You are correct. How to change my code?

I literally already told you in my first comment? and of course then use i instead of i-1... (Note you don't need to change, both are equivalent, it's just nicer and more pythonic)

I'm having trouble understanding what you're trying to do. "Then the matrix of first 5 rows and first 5columns should be zero matrix. The matrix of [6:10, 6:10] should also be zero matrix, etc." Which should not be zero matrixes?

@Barmar Anything that are not diagonal block matrix are not zero matrix.

Ah, now I see it: [0:6, 6:10], [6:10, 6:10], ...

@Barmar exactly! Under d=20, and K =5, For a 100x100 matrix, I want all the 20 diagonal block [1:5, 1:5], [6:10, 6:10],...,[96:100, 96:100] (sorry, I am more familiar with the usual index from matrix and R) are zero matrix.

The simplest way is to first create an all-non-zero matrix, then replace those diagonal sub-matrixes with zeroes, rather than trying to do it all in one loop.

@Barmar I see. Could you give me an answer?

Start with a Kd x Kd non-zero matrix:
side_size = K * d
bnds = [(0, None) for i in range(side_size) for j in range(side_size)]

Then use nested loops to replace the diagonal sub-matrixes with zeroes.
for k in range(0, side_size, K): # k = top-left corner of sub-matrix
    for i in range(k, k+K):
        for j in range(k, k+K):
            bnds[i * side_size + j] = (0, 0)


I think there are a few misconceptions in your question, but i'll try to answer as best as I can understand. The example code you provided stores the matrix as a completely flat list of elements, which I'm not really sure that you want.
If you'd like to create a 2D matrix you can use the following code.
matrix = [[(0,0) if row // k == col // k else (0,None) for col in range(d*k)] for row in range(d*k)]

If you have all of your data structured in K x K chunks, however, i'd recommend using a 4D matrix (which becomes much easier if you use numpy). After you've installed it you can use the following code which essentially creates the same matrix as above but structured differently. In this case matrix will be a d x d matrix of k x k matrices.
import numpy as np

matrix = np.full(shape=(d, d, k, k, 2), fill_value=(0,None))
matrix[range(d), range(d)] = np.full(shape=(k, k, 2), fill_value=(0,0))

If you actually did want to represent the matrix as a completely flat 1-D list for some reason, you can just modify the list comprehension like so.
flat_matrix = [(0,0) if row // k == col // k else (0,None) for col in range(d*k) for row in range(d*k)]


My guess is that this will be consumed by something, and each item in the matrix represents numerical bounds. So (0,  0) locks the value at zero, and (0, None) has no upper bound.

Ahh that makes more sense! Didn't understand that bnds probably stood for "bounds". I'll edit the answer.
